# Detect keyboard layout?

Tags: key-bindings

**Q:** how can I detect the keyboard layout from Emacs?

I'm writing some code that will set keybindings dynamically by selecting easy-to-reach keys (eg, those on home row).  To do this, though, I need to to know which keys correspond to home row on the user's computer.

I could default to assuming that the computer uses the QWERTY layout, but that's not very portable for people using alternate layouts (I, myself, use Dvorak).

*How would I detect the keyboard layout?  Is there anything portable (in pure elisp) that does it, or would one need to drop to the system level to do it?*

(I've browsed through various `*-keyboard-*` and `*-input-method-*` variables, and may have missed something obvious.)

PS: there's an [old SO thread with a similar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813648/emacs-determining-keyboard-layout) that does not answer this question.

Comment: The only portable way of doing this is asking the user to hit a sequence of keys and comparing these against a number of known layouts.  In other words, I'm sure you'd need to do platform-specific queries to find out the currently active layout.