# Generate dynamic keybindings depending on keyboard layout

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keyboard-layout

This is a bit of an esoteric request so I will try to phrase it clearly.

I am currently beginning to learn colemak and doing so through a series of transitional layouts that go by the group name of tarmak. On top of that, I use evil-mode so the spacial relationship between different keybindings is important. Since these tarmak layouts are only temporary, It would be nice to not have to rebind everything repeatedly as I get gradually closer and closer to full colemak.

Is there a emacs package or snippet of code that can remap keys depending on the current keyboard layout of the computer such that the spacial position of keybindings does not change?

Comment: You can have a look at package ergoemacs, that provides bindings to the same physical keys for various layouts. It does need you to tell which layout is currently in use.

Comment: Related: [Detect keyboard layout?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18579/detect-keyboard-layout)

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/misc/ergoemacs_vi_mode.html is another modal keymap that has layouts for azerty, azerty-be, colemak, colemak-mod-dh, dvorak, programer-dvorak, qwerty, qwerty-abnt, qwertz and might be a good example of what you're looking for?
;; "workman"

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly a complete answer to your question, but it may help you as a starting point. My evil-colemak-basics provides Qwerty/Colemak best-of-both-worlds key bindings:

https://github.com/wbolster/evil-colemak-basics

You can use it as a starting point in case you have a different layout.

That said, this is 6 months after you asked your question, so maybe you are using proper Colemak now, in which case this package may be exactly what you are looking for.